# How to read url in java?

Tags: java, jsp, url

Hi I am trying to read a url in java using a simple refular classm then I am getting a string. I am storing that string in 2 different variables and printing that variable. When I print that variable I am getting some Hindi Font and English on my console.

When I try to use the same url on my jsp page I am getting only junk characters. I am not getting hindi  font. But I want the same output here as I am getting on console.

Here is my

**CommoditywiseGetUrl.java**

```
public class CommoditywiseGetUrl {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        URL url;
        try {
            // get URL content

            String a = "http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
            url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

                s = s.replace("~", " ");
                //System.out.println(s);
                StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();

                    String price = str.nextElement().toString();

                    //  System.out.println("Mandi:--->"+mandi);
                    //System.out.println("Price:--->"+price);
                    list1.add(mandi);
                    list2.add(price);
                }
            }
            String item1 = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < list1.size() - 195; i++) {
                System.out.println(list1.get(i));

            }
            for (j = 0; j < list2.size() - 195; j++) {


                System.out.println(list2.get(j));

            }
            br.close();

            //System.out.println(sb);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**My.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    URL url;
    try {
        // get URL content

        String a = "http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
        url = new URL(a);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String s = inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

            s = s.replace("~", " ");
            //System.out.println(s);
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();

                String price = str.nextElement().toString();

                //  System.out.println("Mandi:--->"+mandi);
                //System.out.println("Price:--->"+price);
                list1.add(mandi);
                list2.add(price);
            }
        }
        String item1 = null;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < list1.size() - 195; i++) {
            out.println(list1.get(i));

        }
        for (j = 0; j < list2.size() - 195; j++) {


            out.println(list2.get(j));

        }
        br.close();

        //System.out.println(sb);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

%>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try httpclient or jsoup instead. Its a pin constructing standard request by hand like you have done.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like a character encoding issue.

You can encode character to UTF-8 as specified in your JSP as below,

`Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)`

Comment: I did not get it properly

Comment: The data you get from the url might be in a specific format (may not be UTF-8), In the the JSP You have specified that char format as UTF-8. The mismatch with encoding can cause data to be displayed as junk characters.

Comment: how i will get know what format is it and why this is displaying right  data on my console

Comment: The data is indeed UTF-8. .encode would make sense on the *sender* side; the receiver needs to *decode*, which you could do explicitly, but InputStreamReader with 2-arg ctor more easily does it for you.  The JSP encoding directive controls output of the page, and (possibly?) input of a form from the page, but not explicit I/O to another server like this.